# Creating functions in R

Tags: r, function

I want to create a function that takes a character value `x`. If the value starts with the letter "A", the function should return "Apple", and so forth.

```
test_df <- function(x){  
  if (input 'a75'){ "apple75"   } 
  else if (input "d21"){ "dragonfruit21"   } 
  }
```

Comment: why should it return `Apple`? Why not return `Apricot` or even `America` etc? Where does  `Apple` come from?

Comment: Im trying to create a function that returns an output. The list below shows what the function should return based on the starting letter.

* "A" -- "Apple"
* "I" -- "Icecream"
* "J" -- "Jam"
* "K" -- "Kangaroo"

Comment: where are the inputs and where are the outputs?\

Comment: @onyambu The OP wants to know about a method for accomplishing a specific task, he/she gives an example of what he/she has and what he/she needs as result, so it is not relevant for you to know why assign apple or america or something else to a.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
test_df <- function(x){
  x <- unlist(strsplit(x, ""))
  string <- if(x[1] == "a"){
    paste0("apple", paste0(x[-1], collapse = ""))
  } else{
    if(x[1] == "d") {
      paste0("dragonfruit", paste0(x[-1], collapse = ""))
    } 
  }
   return(string)
    
}

> test_df('a75')
[1] "apple75"
> test_df('d21')
[1] "dragonfruit21"
```

You can even use `Vectorize` and give a vector as input:

```
test_df_v <- Vectorize(test_df)
test_df_v(c('a75','d21', 'aZ45'))
            a75             d21            aZ45 
      "apple75" "dragonfruit21"      "appleZ45"
```

Now you have a starting point, anything else you want o add, then would be easier from now on.

Comment: How can I loop this function (test_df) to change each value in a particular column of a dataset? I have tried using the  "for" function, but there seems to be an error.

Comment: You can use any of the apply family functions, for example: apply(df, 2, test_df_v)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this below code

### code

```r
library(stringr)

test_df <- function(x){
if (str_detect(x,'^a')) {
  return('apple75')
} else if (str_detect(x,'^d')) {
  return('dragonfruit75') 
} else {
  return('no input match')
}
}

test_df('a75')
```

### output

```r
[1] "apple75"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test_fun <- function(x){
  x <- tolower(x) # Ensure the input is all lowercase
  if(startsWith(x, 'a')) "apple75"  
  else if (startsWith(x, 'd'))  "dragonfruit21" 
}

test_fun('A')
[1] "apple75"
```

Answer (score 0):

One way that might be easier to keep track of the options would be to create a lookup table within the function and select from that:

```
startsWith <- function(x){
  firstletter = substr(tolower(x), 0,1)
  lookup = data.frame(firstletter = c("a",       "b",        "c",      "d"),
                      associated  = c("apple75", "Banana69", "Carrot18", "dragonfruit21")
                      )
  
  return(lookup$associated[which(lookup$firstletter==firstletter)])
}

startsWith("apple")
#[1] "apple75"

startsWith("drnking")
#[1] "dragonfruit21"
```

Comment: How can I loop this function (test_df) to change each value in a particular column of a dataset? I have tried using the "for" function, but there seems to be an error.

Comment: use sapply: sapply(c("apple43", "card24", "drinking", "dog"), FUN=startsWith)